# Configure connect mirror maker with MTLS for only target and plaintext for source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker, mtls

I am running a mirror maker 2.0 (binary from kafka 2.6) and my source cluster is configured with plain text where as my target cluster is enabled with ssl

I have created proper keys and made sure first connection is working fine with below command,

```
./kafka-topics.sh --list topics --bootstrap-server my-target:9092 --command-config ssl_properties
```

ssl_properties file is as below,

> security.protocol=SSL
> ssl.truststore.location=/opt/keys/client.truststore
> ssl.truststore.password=123456
> ssl.keystore.location=/opt/keys/jacek.keystore
> ssl.keystore.password=123456    ssl.key.password=password

Now when I try to run the mirror maker it is failing with following error, with similar config in the mirror maker config file like below,

```
> source.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT target.security.protocol=SSL
> target.ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/poc-config/keys/client.truststore
> target.ssl.truststore.password=123456
> target.ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/poc-config/keys/jacek.keystore
> target.ssl.keystore.password=123456 target.ssl.key.password=password
```

**Error:**

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1605011994642, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1605011994743) timed out at 1605011994643 after 1 attempt(s)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata
> [2020-11-10 12:40:24,642] INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-8 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
> [2020-11-10 12:40:24,643] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-8] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager:235)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1605012024643, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1attempt(s)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
> [2020-11-10 12:40:24,644] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:668)
> [2020-11-10 12:40:24,644] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:672)
> [2020-11-10 12:40:24,644] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:678)
> [2020-11-10 12:40:24,645] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker:304)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:70)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:51)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.addHerder(MirrorMaker.java:235)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.lambda$new$1(MirrorMaker.java:136)
> at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.(MirrorMaker.java:136)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.(MirrorMaker.java:148)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.java:291)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1605012024641, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1605012024742)timed out at 1605012024642 after 1 attempt(s)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
> ... 7 more
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1605012024641, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1605012024742) timed out at 1605012024642 after 1 attempt(s)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes

Comment: it was an issue with replication factor, both source and destination should have the same replication factor. The error is nothing to do with ssl and it works fine